# Merge replication commands being executed for a particular table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, merge-replication

Is there a table where I can view the merge replication commands being executed for a particular table? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, I looked and the nearest object that I could find to help me were the conflict tables that had the conflicting data in them.